# Flutter: Scrolling stucks in weird loop

Tags: ios, flutter, listview, scroll

I have a `ListView` in page. Each item is wrapped with `StreamBuilder`, which checks if item is deleted or not. If item is deleted, it will show `SizedBox`, otherwise, it will show the item. However, when the item does get deleted and I try to scroll, it keeps scrolling at the same position. This issue occurs on real device(iPhone) in both TextFlight and App Store versions. I have not tested this on Android. I am posting code and video. I have posted this issue on [Github](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/144299) too

```
ListView.builder(
  // primary: false,
  shrinkWrap: true,
  itemCount: upcomingEventsList?.length,
  keyboardDismissBehavior:
      ScrollViewKeyboardDismissBehavior.onDrag,
  itemBuilder: (context, listViewIndex) {
    var listViewEventsRecord =
        upcomingEventsList![listViewIndex];
    return StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
        key: ValueKey(listViewEventsRecord.reference.id),
        stream: firestore
            .doc(listViewEventsRecord.reference.path)
            .snapshots(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData && (!snapshot.data!.exists))
            return SizedBox.shrink();
          listViewEventsRecord = snapshot.hasData
              ? EventsRecord.fromSnapshot(snapshot.data!)
              : listViewEventsRecord;

          return FFAppState().isGridView
                  ? EventListBiggerWidget(
                      key: Key(
                        'Keygib_${listViewEventsRecord.reference.id}',
                      ),
                      event: listViewEventsRecord,
                    )
                  : Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
                          8, 0, 8, 0),
                      child: EventSmallListPublicWidget(
                        key: Key(
                          'Keylwy_${listViewEventsRecord.reference.id}',
                        ),
                        event: listViewEventsRecord,
                      ),
                    );
        });
  },
),
```

The video is here: [Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1l2CyYqYEHbTWe-GX3OmPGNpSnr9IchJX/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: `stream: firestore
            .doc(listViewEventsRecord.reference.path)
            .snapshots(),`   DO NOT build the stream in the stream: parameter of the StreamBuilder.  Lift the state.  See https://youtu.be/sqE-J8YJnpg for details.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I will let you know if this fixes the issue, but, shouldn't it work regardless? Why does it get stuck like that? I have seen similar issue in some other apps that I use. Maybe it's a Flutter/iOS issue.

Comment: The solution from the video did not work.